# remove ID in array when select - unselect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm looking for a way that when unselected a line, for remove the number in the array.

> when selected > id : [2, 7, 8]

==> Probleme when i unselected one item : example with id 8 :

> when unselected > id : [2, 7, 8]

the id 8 stay in my array.

==> Problem when I unselected one item and i click again :

> id : [2, 7, 8, 8]

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        id: [],
    };
    this.onRowSelect = this.onRowSelect.bind(this);
    this.onSelectAll = this.onSelectAll.bind(this);
}

onRowSelect(row, isSelected, e) {
    let rowStr = '';
    for (const prop in row) {
        rowStr += prop + ': "' + row[prop] + '"';
        if (isSelected == true){
            this.setState({ id: [...this.state.id, row.id] })
        }
    }
    console.log(`is selected: ${isSelected}, ${rowStr}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the map function (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map):

```
onSelectAll(isSelected, rows) {
    console.log(`is select all: ${isSelected}`);
    if (isSelected) {
        console.log('Current display and selected data: ');
        this.setState({ id: [...this.state.id, ...rows.map(x=>x.id)] })
    } else {
        console.log('unselect rows: ');
        const ids = this.state.id.reduce((acc,id)=>{
            return rows.find(x=>x.id === id) ? acc : [...acc,id]
        },[])
        this.setState({ id: [...ids] })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will look to do as before, remove the data from id when i unselect.

Comment: I edit with the reduce code to unselect all rows id ;)

Answer (score 1):

When isSelect is false, you have to set in your state your array without the selected row id. the filter function do it to you.

```
    onRowSelect(row, isSelected, e) {
      let rowStr = '';
      for (const prop in row) {
        rowStr += prop + ': "' + row[prop] + '"';
        if (isSelected == true){
          this.setState({ id: [...this.state.id, row.id] })
        }else{
          this.setState({ id: [...this.state.id.filter(x=>x!==row.id)] })
        }
      }
      console.log(`is selected: ${isSelected}, ${rowStr}`);
    }
```

Comment: I posted a very similar problem would you be able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

When i use

> this.setState({ id: [...this.state.id, rows[i].id] })

he only retrieves the last ID of the section

```
onSelectAll(isSelected, rows) {
        console.log(`is select all: ${isSelected}`);
        if (isSelected) {
            console.log('Current display and selected data: ');
        } else {
            console.log('unselect rows: ');
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            console.log(rows[i].id);
            this.setState({ id: [...this.state.id, rows[i].id] })
        }
    }
```